# How to log exception parameter values

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have a asp.net website.
In this website I have made many function, these function are called inside another function. I want to write all the data that was passed to the function along with the value to a log file.
let us suppose an example

```
public void MyFunction(int a, int b)
{
try
 {
   int result=a/b;
 }
 catch
 {
   Some Code Here so that I can catch the exception and write into my log file like 
   /**Function Name: MyFunction**/
   /**Parameter a=9;**/
   /**b=0;**/
 }
}
```

I have searched for postsharp but it doesnt work with website.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or Classic ASP? The solutions offered will differ greatly.

Answer (score 0):

use a [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) block

i.e.

```
try {
  // call a method
} catch(Exception e) {
  // an error occurred, details are in the local variable e
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a function/method that is part of the .NET library then you can check the documentation which will list all of the possible exceptions. E.g. See "Exceptions": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx

You can then use [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to catch any exceptions that may be thrown.

Comment: I can catch the exception, that is not my problem but I want the list parameter values passed in the function. I want paramter values

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ELMAH.
It is quite is to install and configure.
You will be up and running in no time.
If you want to log also info about passed in parameters I would just rethrow an exception which contains all this info.
Elmah will record it for you

** EDIT **

Here you have a tutorial on how to get up and running.
I recommend that you use nuget, here is a nice step through:
[elmah-using-nuget-what-they-are-and-why-you-should-use-them-part-1/](http://gregorsuttie.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/elmah-using-nuget-what-they-are-and-why-you-should-use-them-part-1/)